# How should my android app connect to Exchange server?

Tags: android, outlook, webdav, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I want to get tasks from an exchange server for sync in an android app. I'm not interested in contacts, emails or calendar items, just tasks.

There seems to be a few ways to connect to an exchange server but the documentation is both vast and opaque.

My server has OWA enabled but the [API seems unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142564%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: My original need to sync tasks was satisfied by an existing app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.inote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WebDAV [search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143053%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx) method you can query an Exchange store for items with content type [taskfolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa123752%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx).

Updating items with the WebDAV protocol is accomplished either using an HTTP PUT operation for files, or by using [the PROPPATCH method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878643%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx) for items only containing properties. Since task items not necessarily are associated with files I assume you must use the PROPPATCH method to create items in the taskfolder.

**Update**: as of Exchange 2010, the WebDAV protocol is [no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579227%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx). Instead, [a web service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) is available. Here's an example on [how to get a Task item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581352%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx).

Clarification: the web service api was introduced in [Exchange Server 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

To detect which Exchange version you're talking to I suggest doing a "probing" approach. Try some essential web service calls to detect 2007 and 2010, preferably using the [`Autodiscover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204078%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) operation. If these do not work, probe the WebDAV interface for earlier versions.

Comment: Excellent information. Thank you. Is there a WebDAV method for updating the taskfolders?

Comment: Thanks again. Final clarification before marking this question answered: how do I detect the whether the Exchange server is 2010 or an earlier one?

Comment: @blokeley, I have same requirement What is the endpoint to post the request to get the Tasks?